# Python 'none' acting weird from one version to another

Tags: python

I'm working on an open source project. Python was upgraded, I THINK from 2.5 to 2.6, and this problem came up.

`get_custom_fields(self.env)` was called.  self.env was None.

```
def get_custom_fields(self, customfield=None):
        if not customfield:   
            ...
        else:                 
            ...
```

Previously this worked fine, and the 'if not' part went through. After the upgrade though, the else started going instead. After removing the self.env, it again goes through the first part. This fixes the problem, but I'm curious why this happened. Did the python upgrade change how optional arguments handle None for some conditionals?

Comment: Try `print`ing `customfield` to see what the actual value of it is when the function is called.

Comment: Even better: `print repr(customfield)`. `None` is not the same as `'None'`, although plain `print` would show the same.

Answer (score 1):

Although `None` is still false, it is always recommended to compare to it using `is` for performance and correctness reasons (i.e. `if foo is None`).

Comment: Performance is the least reason. `if x:` checks the value for "truthness", which is much more than being `None` - empty collections, for instance, sometimes make quite valid values, but only `if x is None:` will correctly recognize them as such.

Comment: Thanks, I was being ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

> Did the python upgrade change how optional arguments handle `None` for some conditionals?

No. `None` is still false. Check the value of `self.env`, it might have been set in a way that relied on implementation details. Someone may have compared strings with `is` instead of `==`, for example.